# Passing Oracle rows result to C function via Array for computation

Tags: c, oracle, oracle11g

I want to perform computing of row results in a shared C compiled program.

I want to do something like :

```
select myfunction( select col1 from table1 ) from dual;
```

Actually I only can do :

```
select myfunction(4,5,6) from dual;
```

I have a table like this :

```
create table table1 (col1 float);
  insert into table1 values (4);
  insert into table1 values (5);
  insert into table1 values (6);
```

My C program (compiled with : gcc -shared -o $ORACLE_HOME/lib/exec_docalc.so exec_docalc.c )

```
#include <stdio.h>
int exec_docalc ( int p1 , int p2, int p3 )
{
  int result;
  result =  p1 + p2 + p3;
  return result;
}
```

SQL :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE LIBRARY docalcLIB UNTRUSTED
 AS '/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_2/lib/exec_docalc.so';

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunction
(P1  BINARY_INTEGER, P2  BINARY_INTEGER, P3  BINARY_INTEGER)
RETURN BINARY_INTEGER
AS LANGUAGE C
LIBRARY docalcLIB
NAME "exec_docalc";
```